# Passing List between C# Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I am trying to learn passing a list between two C# forms using constructors as shown below. On the first form I did:

```
List<Cat> myCatList;
//list populating function...
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    df = new DisplayForm(myCatList);   
    df.Show();
    this.Hide();
 }
```

On the next form, I tried to receive the data as shown below:

```
List<Cat> catList; 
public DisplayForm(List<Cat> catList)
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.catList = catList;
  }
```

But I always get an error on the second form constructor saying:

Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<_05_WindowsFormsAppCat.Cat>' is less accessible than method '_05_WindowsFormsAppCat.DisplayForm.DisplayForm(System.Collections.Generic.List<_05_WindowsFormsAppCat.Cat>)'

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the definition of `Cat`. I bet it's not `public`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you declare the `Cat` class?  It must be publicly accessible to the `DisplayForm` class.  You may have to add the `public` keyword to its declaration.

This is known as the accessibility of a type or a member.

Here is a reference of the different levels and their default values:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

I'm guessing that your `Cat` type was either in another assembly (project) as your `DisplayForm`, in which case it was by default not visible to classes in that project, or that you defined it as a nested class of your first Form class which would have made it `private` and accessible in the scope of that Form.

Answer (score 9):

The `List` part is a complete red herring here. You'd get exactly the same problem if your constructor had a `Cat` parameter instead of a `List<Cat>` parameter.

Your `Cat` type is probably internal, because you haven't declared it as `public`. Therefore you can't use it in the signature of a *public* member such as this:

```
public DisplayForm(List<Cat> catList)
```

Options:

- Make `Cat` a public class
- Make your `DisplayForm` constructor internal

Personally I'm all for keeping things as private as is practical - although for small projects it won't make much difference, particularly for apps which are just a single assembly anyway. Most developers *tend* to err on the side of making everything public, which is a mistake IMO, but it's a judgement call. Both of the above options will work fine... but you should at least *think* about whether you want any other assembly to know about the `Cat` type (or indeed whether you want code in other assemblies to be able to call that constructor).